# How to convert Json sub attributes into desired object?

Tags: c#, json

I have a sample json file as below.

```
{
  "TestOneConfig":  {
    "SvcUrl":   "www.abc.com/",
    "Port": "3455"
  },
  "LiveTestConfig": {
    "ConnString": "abcd"
  }
}
```

And I have class model for "TestOneConfig" as below

```
public class TestOneConfig
    {
        public string SvcUrl { get; set; }
        public string Port { get; set; }
    }
```

How to deserialize the "TestOneConfig" sub items to the class model.

I tried as below but did not work. I used NewtonJsoft.

```
 using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("appsettings.json"))
                {
                    var settingsJson = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    dynamic settings1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(settingsJson);
                    dynamic settings2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestOneConfig>(settings1.TestOneConfig);
                }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything - there is no code there that shows any effort at all

Comment: I was trying as added @Plutonix

Comment: @Nandakumar1712 This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve? Is this by chance a .net-core project?

Comment: @Nkosi I want to read some settings in runtime from a Json file for my tests. I don't want to read individual elements. I model the runtime settings value to a class and map those things with the settings Json for the ease of access and bundling data in a nice way. I made it work now as below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), you could do something like this:

```
var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(json);
var testOneConfig = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestOneConfig>(jsonObj["TestOneConfig"].ToString());
```

Alternatively, you can just use the `jsonObj` variable which holds the entire json string, instead of deserializing individual properties, to access the fields you need:

```
var testOneConfigSvcUrl = jsonObj["TestOneConfig"]["SvcUrl"].ToString();
var testOneConfigPort = jsonObj["TestOneConfig"]["Port"].ToString();
var liveTestConfigConnString = jsonObj["LiveTestConfig"]["ConnString"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @PoweredByOrange. That helped. Since I used NewtonJsoft, only the format is changed. It become as below

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("appsettings.json"))
   {
        dynamic settingsJson = reader.ReadToEnd();
        var settings = JObject.Parse(settingsJson);
        var testOneConfigObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestOneConfig>(settings.TestOneConfig.ToString());                    
    }
```